# Ultrasonic sensor showing weird reading

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, code-review

When i run a test code in Newping library for ultrasonic sensor SR04 then in works properly but when i run the actual code for obstacle avoiding robot then it shows 0 cm everytime. This means that wiring is correct but there is something wrong in my code below

```
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <AFMotor.h> //import your motor shield library

#define TRIGGER_PIN  12
#define ECHO_PIN     11
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);

AF_DCMotor motor1(1, MOTOR12_64KHZ); // set up motors.
AF_DCMotor motor2(2, MOTOR12_8KHZ);

int distance;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);
  distance = sonar.ping_cm(); // start the scan
  delay(20);
  if (distance < 2) {   
   Serial.println("Close Obstacle detected!" );
   Serial.println("Obstacle Details:");
   Serial.print("Distance From Robot is " );
   Serial.print(distance);
   Serial.print( " CM!");// print out the distance in centimeters.
   delay(10);
   Serial.println (" The obstacle is declared a threat due to close distance. ");
   Serial.println (" Turning !");
   motor1.run(FORWARD);  // Turn as long as there's an obstacle ahead.
   motor2.run(BACKWARD);

}
  else {
   Serial.println("No obstacle detected. going forward");
   delay(15);
   motor1.run(FORWARD); //if there's no obstacle ahead, Go Forward! 
   motor2.run(FORWARD);
  }
}
```

Test code for sensor which worked:-

```
#include <NewPing.h>

#define TRIGGER_PIN  12
#define ECHO_PIN     11
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);
  Serial.print("Ping: ");
  Serial.print(sonar.ping_cm());
  Serial.println("cm");
}
```

Tell me whats wrong here

[image: motor shield used is from dk electronics]

Motor Shield used below
Wiring of sensor is connected to Arduino below the shield

Comment: replace the whole  `if-else` loop with `Serial.print(distance);` .... what does it print now?

Comment: The NewPing library returns zero when there is no echo detected. And 2 cm may be too short. If I remember correctly, this is the minimal distance that these sensors can detect.

Comment: yes i tried serial.print and showed some reading. But now it goes to 1000cm :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
unsigned int distance;
```

Instead of

```
int distance;
```

It could also be the motor shield that is using the same pins as your ultrasonic sensor.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Using serial.print() instead of distance variable helped.

Comment: And your sure that your motor shield is not conflicting ? What make/model is it ?

Comment: its like the one in dk electronics. Now again the sensor is showing 0cm so i think you are right. I have done sensor wiring under the shield so is that a good method?

Comment: Not sure about the wiring without seeing it. What I would recommend is trying your sketch without the motor shield.

Comment: I tried the test code without motor shield and it worked but doesnt work with motor shield on it.

Comment: According to this schematic pin 11 and 12 are used by the motor shield: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=211225.0;attach=71519

Comment: You could try using A0 and A1 for the sensor. In theory should work. If not you will need to use an Arduino with more I/O like the Arduino Mega 2560